# Child website presentation folders

Tags: sxa

Can all presentation folders be deleted from child websites in a tenant that has 1 shared site from where the presentation is controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily remove those items using PowerShell script but I would recommend not to do it. SXA has a lot of queries which are expecting Presentation item (and its child items) to be in the site.

If you want you can remove e.g. Rendering Variants created to each site or Partial Designs if you have a global set of them.

Comment: By 'Remove' you mean removing the Rendering Variants item itself or its contents? Seeing you mention that SXA expects Presentation and its child items to be present...

Comment: Specyfic rendering variants for renderings.

Comment: Ok, so the Item itself should be left alone but the "default" underneath can be safely removed leaving only the empty structure? Will all renderings then correctly fall back to the default rendering variant on the shared website?

Comment: If none of the variants is selected in the rendering control properties than the first available one will be taken. So if you have a global set of variants in your shared site and you won't be using only those, then you can remove ones from the site. Even if you won't select it manually (variant in the rendering) then it should pick up first available one (from a global site). Do a test and remove variants for one rendering in one site - check if this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: OK, I did some digging and here's what I found: You can safely delete 'most' nodes under Rendering Variants without any issue. The problems start when removing Rich Text for example because the pipeline that fetches the Rendering Variants for a Linked Compatible Rendering does not take into account Shared sites.

Comment: This might be a bug. I'll inform our QAs on Monday about it.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do this without breaking everything.**

The concept of shared sites was introduced lately and most of the logic still rely on items under **Presentation**. Few things from my head:

- current site theme,
- templates to design mapping,
- asset optimizer settings,
- cache settings,
- available renderings (toolbox).

## Alternative

I would recommend taking a different approach for that.
This is a hack, not a recommended/supported way of work.

1. Create shared site - **S**
2. Create normal site - **A**
3. Remove Presentation node under `A/Presentation`
4. Clone `S/Presentation` to `A/Presentation`
5. Open `A/Settings/Shared Sites Settings` and add cloned `A/Presentation` (from `S/Presentation`). This step will help changes from clone sources to auto-populate under other sites.
6. [Optionally] Mark `A/Presentation` and all children as Protected/Hidden.

That way you should be able to control every site that contains cloned Presentation node via changes in the shared site.

You could potentially do the same with Settings but be careful. I tested only obvious cases and I am not sure where things can blow up ;)